# react-apollo: How to deal with immutability in update and updateQuery?

Tags: apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I am using [react-apollo](https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo) in my React application. Now it comes to pagination to fetch more data. Independent from the pagination, how do you update the state in `updateQuery` or `update`? Treating the deeply nested data structure as immutable makes it verbose, but I wouldn't want to add a helper library to it.

```
fetchMore({
  variables: {
    cursor: cursor,
  },
  updateQuery: (previousResult, { fetchMoreResult }) => {
    return {
      ...previousResult,
      author: {
        ...previousResult.author,
        articles: {
          ...previousResult.author.articles,
          ...fetchMoreResult.author.articles,
          edges: [
            ...previousResult.author.articles.edges,
            ...fetchMoreResult.author.articles.edges,
          ],
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

Is it okay to mutate the `previousResult` instead or does it go against the philosophy of Apollo?

```
const { pageInfo, edges } = fetchMoreResult.author.articles;
previousResult.author.articles.edges.concat(edges);
previousResult.author.articles.pageInfo = pageInfo;
return previousResult;
```

Or is there another way to update the state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/features/cache-updates.html#updateQueries):

> Note that the function must not alter the prev object (because prev is compared with the new object returned to see what changes the function made and hence what prop updates are needed).

I would just bite the bullet and use [immutability-helper](https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper) like the docs recommend. Barring that, you could make a copy of the object first (`Object.assign({}, fetchMoreResult)`) and then you can do what you want to the copy.

Comment: Okay. I wouldn't want to bite this bullet and just stick to JavaScript ES6 and beyond, because I wouldn't want to use yet another immutability library. But thanks for your answer regarding the immutability!